# Añadir elementos en una pila

Tags: java, lista, estructuras-de-datos, pilas

Al ejecutar este codigo me marca un error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0

Entonces en una pila nunca se le podrán añadir objetos a partir de la posición n, n=1,2,...,infinito, siempre se empezara en la posición 0??

Mi idea era que `pila.add("(");` lo pusiera en la posicion 0.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
   
 
    LinkedList<String> pila=new LinkedList<>();
 
    
    pila.add(1,"1");
    pila.add(2,"2");
    pila.add(3,"3");
    pila.add(4,"*");
    
    pila.add("(");
    System.out.println(pila);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Estás intentando añadir un elemento a un índice que no existe

Tu problema radica en que al crear la lista, su tamaño es de 1 nodo (índice 0), pero intentas añadir un elemento al **segundo nodo, que no existe**. En efecto, deberías empezar a añadir elementos por el índice 0.

Ahora, veo que estás intentando insertar en un índice concreto. **Eso es precisamente lo que una pila y una cola intentan evitar**.

## Una pila es una estructura de tipo LIFO

Las estructuras de tipo **LIFO** y **FIFO** no te permiten añadir elementos en una posición arbitraria, sino que **la inserción y extracción de datos están siempre ligadas al primer o último elemento**.

Están diseñadas para que no tengas que preocuparte de en qué orden están los elementos.

### Estructuras de tipo LIFO

LIFO es acrónimo de *Last In, First Out*. Las **pilas** cumplen esta norma.

Piensa en una pila como una **pila de platos que lavar**. El primer plato sucio que colocas se queda abajo. Y cuando los laves, ese primer plato será el último en salir.

### Estructuras de tipo FIFO

FIFO es acrónimo de *First In, First Out*. Las **colas** cumplen esta norma.

Puedes imaginarte una **cola de supermercado**. La primera persona que llega a la cola es la primera persona que saldrá.

### En cuanto a tu implementación

Si quieres implementar una pila (**LIFO**), las colecciones de java ofrecen un par de formas:

#### Utilizar la clase [`Stack`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html).

Esta clase representa exactamente la pila que tú buscas. pero tiene un problema. Como pone en la documentación, hereda de la clase `Vector`, una clase que está poco más que olvidada. Además, al heredar y no implementar, obtienes un comportamiento poco flexible y que ofrece cosas que no quieres, algo que no es recomendable.

#### Utilizar la interfaz [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) y sus implementaciones.

> Nota: entre las implementaciones de `Deque` se encuentra `LinkedList`

`Deque` se pronuncia "Deck", es decir "Baraja" y soporta operaciones tanto LIFO como FIFO. Podrías tomarlo como una **fusión entre colas y pilas**.

Esta interfaz es más moderna y ya no extiende de `Vector`. Es cierto que `Deque` ofrece inserción y extracción por ambos extremos, lo cual *podría* ser más funcionalidad de la que buscas, pero también ofrece flexibilidad a la hora de elegir si quieres una estructura FIFO o LIFO.

En mi opinión, si quieres una estructura **Exclusivamente FIFO o LIFO**, deberías utilizar esta interfaz y su implementación [`ArrayDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html).

#### Un ejemplo de pila:

```
// Usando un Deque como pila LIFO    
Deque<String> pila = new ArrayDeque<>();
    
pila.push("M"); // Entra primero, sale el ultimo
pila.push("i");
pila.push("c");
pila.push("h");
pila.push("e");
pila.push("l");
pila.push("l");
pila.push("e"); // Entra ultimo, sale el primero       

int size = pila.size();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    System.out.println(pila.pop());
}
```

---

Salida:

```
e
l
l
e
h
c
i
M
```

Comment: Hablando de la clase Stack, a qué te refieres cuando dices: 'al heredar y no implementar, obtienes un **comportamiento poco flexible** y que ofrece **cosas que no quieres**'?

Comment: En concreto, y teniendo en cuenta que el propósito de `Stack` es ofrecer una estructura LIFO, no se debería poder acceder a elementos por el índice (podría llevar a cosas como eliminación de un elemento cuando no se debe), pero como `Stack` ES un `Vector`, no hay manera de evitar eso. Esa es una de las razones por las que hoy en día se prefiere utilizar interfaces sobre clases.

Answer (score 3):

De acuerdo a la documentación de la clase `LinkedList`, la excepción se produce por: `IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range (index < 0 || index > size())`. Cuando creas la `pila` esta esta vacia por lo cual su tamaño es cero (`0`), cuando intentas hacer `pila.add(1,"1");` estas diciendo que en el `index 1` adicione el valor `"1"` pero el `index` es mayor que el tamaño de la pila en ese momento, la forma correcta es `pila.add(0,"1");`

Ahora como el comportamiento de una pila es que el último que entra es el primero que sale entonces siempre debes de adicionar o remover con el index 0

```
pila.add(0,"1");
pila.add(0,"2");
pila.add(0,"3");
pila.add(0,"*");
pila.add(0,"(");

String iPila = pila.remove(0);
```

Si quieres una implementación más especifica de pila, puedes usar la clase Stack https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html

```
Deque<String> stack = new ArrayDeque<String>();
stack.push("1");
stack.push("2");
stack.push("3");
stack.push("*");
stack.push("(");
System.out.println(stack.pop()); //aca imprime y remueve ( que fue el último elemento ingresado
```

Answer (score 1):

La idea de las pilas y colas es no saber las posiciones de los elementos y que uses solamente el elemento que está disponible, el cual es la cabeza/cabecera o head.

Sobre tu problema, sucede que tu lista `LinkedList` está vacía, por lo que no puede agregar un elemento en la posición 1. Primero debes agregar un elemento en la posición inicial. El método `List#insert(int index, E elem)` indica que debe existir dicho elemento.

---

Nota a parte, para trabajar con colas en Java es mejor usar la interfaz [`Queue<E>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html). Ejemplo:

```
Queue<String> cola = new LinkedList<>();
cola.offer("1");
cola.offer("Hello");
cola.offer("World");
while (!cola.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println(cola.poll());
}
```

Salida:

```
1
Hello
World
```

Para interactuar con pilas, si bien existe una clase [`Stack`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html), no se recomienda su uso puesto que extiende de `Vector` el cual es una clase técnicamente depreciada. En su lugar, es mejor usar la interfaz [`Deque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) y una implementación como `ArrayDeque` o `LinkedList`:

```
Deque<String> deque = new ArrayDeque<>();
deque.push("World");
deque.push("Hello");
deque.push("1");
while (!deque.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println(deque.pop());
}
```

Salida:

```
1
Hello
World
```

Answer (score 1):

Me temo que el error se produce en el primer intento de añadir a la colección en una posición inferior a su tamaño actual. No se puede añadir en una posición 1 si la lista tiene tamaño 0.
Lo que pretendes se puede hacer perfectamente con la clase `LinkedList` pero debes respetar el tamaño de la lista a la hora de usar el índice en la inserción:

```
LinkedList<String> pila = new LinkedList<>();

pila.add("1");
pila.add("2");
pila.add("3");
pila.add("*");

pila.add(0,"("); //desplaza resto elementos a su índice + 1
System.out.println(pila); //[(, 1, 2, 3, *]
```

El método `add` está sobrecargado, debes usar la versión adecuada en cada caso si pretendes simular el comportamiento de una pila